# Storage::disk('s3')->get('path/fileName.jpg') is not working when Laravel upgraded from 5.6 to 9 with base64 encoded file

Tags: php, laravel-5, base64, storage, laravel-9

On the AWS s3 bucket, I have a base64 encoded image file which I need to download when the route is accessed it's working correctly with Laravel version 5.6 when the version is upgraded from 5.6 to 9 it returns null.

```
$mime = Storage::disk($storage)->mimeType($path);
$size = Storage::disk($storage)->size($path);

$response = [
    'Content-Type' => $mime,
    'Content-Length' => $size,
    'Content-Description' => 'File Transfer',
    'Content-Disposition' => "attachment; filename=" . $fileName,
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'binary',
];

ob_end_clean();

return \Response::make(Storage::disk($storage)->get($path), 200, $response);
```

Laravel 9:

`Storage::disk($storage)->get($path)` returns null

`Storage::disk($storage)->exists($path)` return true